# Cocoa Formatting string in NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a NSTextView and I am able to successfully load NSString into it and show it. My problem is that my NSString is a list of questions formatted in a way like this.

```
1)fsdfasdfalsfdakf
2)sldfakflafdjaf
3)dslakfaldsflakdf
4)dfladjfakflaf
```

That is how it looks in the NSString variable and I would like it to look the same way in my NSTextView. How do I format this? Thanks!

Comment: Why aren't the questions in separate strings in the first place?  Why are they concatenated already?

Answer (score 0):

Separate them with newline delimiters:

```
1)fsdfasdfalsfdakf\n
2)sldfakflafdjaf\n
3)dslakfaldsflakdf\n
4)dfladjfakflaf
```